# Cassandra store list of objects

Tags: list, cassandra, storage

I need to store a list of map in cassandra. Is that possible?
This is a json representation of my data:

```
{
   "deviceId" : "261e92b8-91af-40da-8ba4-c39d821472ec",
   "sensors": [
   {
       "fieldSensorId": "sensorID",
       "name": "sensorName",
       "location": "sensor location",
       "unit": "value units",
       "notes": "notes"
   },
   {
      "fieldSensorId": "sensorID 2",
      "name": "sensorName 2",
      "location": "sensor location 2",
      "unit": "value units",
      "notes": "notes"
    }
  ]
}
```

CQL:

```
CREATE TABLE device_sensors (
    device_id text,
    sensors list<frozen <map<text,text>>>,
    time timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (device_id)
)
```

Still im not able to insert any data. What is the right way of storing such data in cassandra? Later i will need to query the sensors list
Is it maybe wiser to create a sensors table and use sensor > to reference the sensors?

Comment: What are you using to insert data? in CQLSH it works just fine: `insert into device_sensors (device_id , sensors) VALUES ('121342', [{'1':'2','3':'4'}]);`

Comment: Im using spring-boot-data-cassandra. My Entity:     @Column("device_id")
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "device_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private UUID deviceId;
    private UUID time;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> sensors;  And the error is: "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: String didn't validate."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you declare `devide_id` as `text` in CQL, but you have declared it`UUID` in the source code, and Spring maps it into corresponding type when trying to insert data.  Can you try to add `@CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT)` to the `deviceId` declaration.  You can also remove the `@Column` declaration - the `@PrimaryKeyColumn` should be enough.

Or you can change the table definition to declare `device_id`as `UUID`.

Comment: Working now. device_id was of wrong type. Adjusted to uuid and it works now. thanks!